# Despite my setting up my own logging.properties, everything still also logs to catalina.out. How to stop?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I am using Tomcat version 5.5.x.  My WAR sets its own logging properties successfully and logs to $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/.YYYY-MM-DD.log.  Everything that is written to my log is also written to catalina.out.  Is there a way to stop the redundant logging to catalina.out stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your application's logging configuration so it doesn't log anything to the console/standard out. Tomcat redirects standard out to the `catalina.out` file, so if you see output in `catalina.out` it implies your application is writing to the console.

Comment: Give me at least a hint as how to do this.

Comment: 1. Open up your application's logging configuration 2. remove the part of the configuration sending output to standard out

Comment: So I changed the java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level value from FINE to WARNING and this seems to work.  I realize there will still be some output to catalina.out, but not everything.